# Deserialize json passed by javascript to c#

Tags: c#, javascript, json

Im currently trying to deserialize json that got bassed by javascript this way:

```
window.external.handlemessage(json);
```

And its being handled by c# like this:

```
   public void handlemessage(string json)
   {
            JavaScriptSerializer deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            Dictionary<string, object> deserializedDictionary1 = (Dictionary<string, object>)deserializer.Deserialize(json, typeof(object));
            Dictionary<string, object> deserializedDictionary2 = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
            object objDeserialized = deserializer.DeserializeObject(json);

   }
```

The passing works fine with plain text for example but just not with json..

I've tried several things such as the deserialize example i provided in the handlemessage but the json just returns invalid basicly. And several other examples ive tried just didn`t do it either.

I have tried to deserialized the json with java and serialized it again without no results (incase there were some flaw).

Also Im trying to deserialize the data without knowing the json structure.

Is it even possible to pass json by javascript and unserializing it with c#?

Comment: What about use JSON.NET dll to handle this? http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: So, what's the value of `json`, and, what, if anything, does `deserializer.DeserializeObject()` return?

Comment: json.net is really not an option for me because I want to use a dll less application if you know what i mean.

value of json is : {"text" : "hi"}, yes

Comment: "json.net is really not an option for me because I want to use a dll less application if you know what i mean" - While I know what you mean I can't really fathom *why*. Managed platforms make it easier than ever to bundle a stable set of third-party dependencies with your application, what practical reason do you have to deprive yourself of such a wealth of resources?

Comment: @Marcus - is merging the dll an option then ? https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> Also Im trying to deserialize the data without knowing the json structure.

For that you want to use C#'s `dynamic` type:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic v = js.Deserialize<dynamic>("{\"text\" : \"hi\"}");
```

In fact you can start there for all your data until you understand how the object is being mapped.

Comment: how do you get the data out from v?

Comment: `v.text` should work. Read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx